# FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a react app. I am trying to create a new user with email and password (firebase) but it keep showing this message

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:136:1)
    at _fail (assert.ts:65:1)
    at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index.ts:177:1)
    at async _performSignInRequest (index.ts:195:1)
    at async createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email_and_password.ts:230:1)
    at async handleAdd (New.jsx:69:1)
```

below is my New.jsx code

```
import "./new.scss"
import Navbar from "../../components/navbar/Navbar"
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar"
import DriveFolderUploadOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DriveFolderUploadOutlined';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {addDoc,collection,doc,serverTimestamp,setDoc,} from "firebase/firestore";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db, storage } from "../../firebase";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const New = ({ inputs, title }) => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [per, setPerc] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    const uploadFile = () => {
      const name = new Date().getTime() + file.name;

      console.log(name);
      const storageRef = ref(storage, file.name);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
          setPerc(progress);
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case "paused":
              console.log("Upload is paused");
              break;
            case "running":
              console.log("Upload is running");
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, img: downloadURL }));
          });
        }
      );
    };
    file && uploadFile();
  }, [file]);

  console.log(data);

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    const value = e.target.value;

    setData({ ...data, [id]: value });
  };

  const handleAdd = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        data.email,
        data.password
      );
      await setDoc(doc(db, "owners", res.owner.uid), {
        ...data,
        timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
      });
      navigate(-1)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };


  return (
    <div className="new">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="newContainer">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="top">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
          <div className="left">
            <img
              src={
                file
                  ? URL.createObjectURL(file)
                  : "https://icon-library.com/images/no-image-icon/no-image-icon-0.jpg"
              }
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
          <div className="right">
            <form onSubmit={handleAdd}>
              <div className="formInput">
                <label htmlFor="file">
                  Image: <DriveFolderUploadOutlinedIcon className="icon" />
                </label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="file"
                  onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                  style={{ display: "none" }}
                />
              </div>

              {inputs.map((input) => (
                <div className="formInput" key={input.id}>
                  <label>{input.label}</label>
                  <input
                    id={input.id}
                    type={input.type}
                    placeholder={input.placeholder}
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    required
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
              <button disabled={per !== null && per < 100} type="submit">
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default New;
```

This is my firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGE,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

//Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth();
export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

- I have enabled the email/password provider
- It started not working when I imported the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` from the firebase

Does anyone know how to solve this?

It will store and create new user to the firebase, no error message showing up

Comment: I recommend putting a `console.log(data.email, data.password)` right before you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and checking if those are indeed the values you expect to pass to the API. Most likely they're not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here in your firebase.js file:

```
export const auth = getAuth();
```

add **app** in the parenthesis.

```
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, resolving this issue is a straightforward process. You simply need to go to the Firebase console and activate the sign-in provider. In your specific situation, you should enable the registration using email and password.
[image: An Image of from firebase console]